# Change to "1 question with new activity" display - bug or feature?

Tags: support, bug, design

A while back I noticed that when the SO site shows me the message "1 question with new activity" (well could be more than 1, but that's not relevant), the layout has changed. This is when monitoring a single tag. I initially assumed it was a bug so ignored it, but it's been this way for quite a while now so maybe it's a feature?

Looking at the screenshot below the background of the message in question is a light grey colour, however, it no longer fills the entire bordered space i.e. there is now whitespace between the grey and nearest border. This didn't use to be the case, and I find it irritating :)

Was this an unintentional change or deliberate? If deliberate can it be changed back? If not deliberate can it be fixed?

[image]

Note: This is on Chrome V90.0.4430.93

Comment: How do you get that to come up anyway? I've seen it on Meta and on other sites but never on SO main, I always just assumed it was disabled because of the high question volume.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery ar, thats when watching a single tag. Will update.

Comment: Ah, just got it to come up. Yeah, I'm seeing the same thing on Firefox/macOS.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery The "new activity" indicator/loading is disabled on the SO main questions page. It's not disabled for single tags.

Comment: Was part of another bug that when you clicked on the new activity the new items also had that margin. They fixed the new items but not the "new activity" message

Comment: intentional and deliberate are the same thing.

Comment: The issue is that SE is, for some reason, using a `margin-left: -24px !important;`, on all of the `<div>` elements which hold the question summaries on those pages, which is applied with a `.mln24` class, but the class isn't applied to the `<div>` which holds the new activity link. The overall problem is that they use a `padding-left: 24px !important;`  (using a `pl24` class) on the `<div>`  containing all the above `<div>` elements and then have to use the `margin-left: -24px !important;` on each contained element to get them back to being aligned with the left of the containing `<div>`.

Comment: Yes, the design has been changed a few times — both unintentionally and intentionally. See [New questions displayed offset to existing ones when using “new activity” link](/q/405536/4642212) and [Question list missing left margin/padding](/q/406171/4642212) ([\[1\]](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/361403/289905) and [\[2\]](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/362416/289905) on MSE). I believe that the “x posts with new activity” bar has been messed up since these changes.